Prove $f$ is injective if $\langle f'(x)v,v\rangle > 0$ for all $x \in U$ and all v plus some other conditions
Prove that, for $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$, differentiable on an open convex subset $U \subset\mathbb{R}^m$, if $\langle f'(x)v,v\rangle > 0$ for all $x \in U,  0 \ne v \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then $f$ is injective. 
I know that $\langle f'(x)v,v\rangle > 0 \forall v \ne 0, \forall x \in U$ implies $f'(x)$ is injective for all $x \in U$, and I know that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)$ is injective, then there is a ball $B$ centered at a such that for all $x \in B, f(x) \ne f(a)$. 
I am stuck in this part and cannot draw any other conclusions. Am I going the wrong way?

Yes you are going the wrong way if your approach is to use the inverse function theorem. You haven't used any of your hypotheses. In particular, convex open domain and your given condition on $f'$ is much stronger.

Note that for any $x,y\in\mathbb R^m$, differentiating the function $f\big(y+t(x-y)\big)$ with respect to $t$ yields $f'\big(y+t(x-y)\big) (x-y)$.
Therefore, whenever $x\neq y$, we have
\begin{align*}
(x-y)^\top \big(f(x)-f(y)\big)&=(x-y)^\top\int_0^1 f'\big(y+t(x-y)\big) (x-y) dt\\
&=\int_0^1 (x-y)^\top f'\big(y+t(x-y)\big) (x-y) dt\\
&>0
\end{align*}
Therefore $f(x)\neq f(y)$.
